# Can you have a perfect seal to maintain moisture?

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design, resin, water-resistance

I would like to create a water chamber (Box) that maintains moisture. My main idea right to use a snap-fit model (Two faces). However, I feel that the areas where the two face snap-fit will allow air to go through and evaporate the water. In simple terms, I would like to create a snap-fit box that can maintain water inside like a water bottle. (Moisture cage)

Note:

- the snap-fit edges are small (gasket is hard to implement)
- the web part will be covered (ignore it)
- I use Formlab 3 SLA resin printer

I there something I can use to perfectly seal the moisture inside? or coat my box from the inside to prevent air exchange?

[image]

Comment: RTV aka caulk is a common sealant. usual trouble with it (and most other methods) is that once you seal, you'll have difficulty unsealing again.  It is possible to make extremely thin gaskets with the right mold.  You may want to try designing a mold that fits one side of the clam.  If you have issues with RTV, there are vinyl compounds that are thinner- sometimes used for applying grips to tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand how you can keep moisture, since the model you show is full of holes.

However, assuming you are closing them or something else, then you can use "rotational moulding": put some liquid sealant inside the box, close the box, then start rotating it in every direction so that the sealant coats all the internal surfaces.